# windows 10 port forwarding 445

Tags: port-forwarding, windows-10, ssh-tunnel, server-message-block

I followed this instruction:
https://www.nikhef.nl/~janjust/CifsOverSSH/Win8Loopback.html
and something strange is happen:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=446 listenaddress=10.255.255.1 connectaddress=10.255.255.1 connectport=44445 protocol=tcp
```

is working perfect:

```
netstat -an | find ":446"

  TCP    10.255.255.1:446       0.0.0.0:0              LISTEN
```

But I dont know why, but:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=445 listenaddress=10.255.255.1 connectaddress=10.255.255.1 connectport=44445 protocol=tcp
```

does not work at all:

```
netstat -an | find ":445"

  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTEN

  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTEN
```

I should see here something like:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTEN

  TCP    10.255.255.1:445       0.0.0.0:0              LISTEN

  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTEN
```

I have no idea, why this is not working. May someone has a good hint for me?

Answer (score 3):

Port 445 is used by Windows File Sharing services by default. If you use `netstat` with the `-o -b` flags, you'll receive something like:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
```

where the `4` at the end of first line is the PID. You can see a similar question about the message *Can not obtain ownership information* [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13484595/1190388) and [on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/43318/123710).

---

You can free up the port by disabling NetBT service by following the [Microsoft's help article here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/313314/how-to-disable-netbios-over-tcp-ip-by-using-dhcp-server-options).

> To disable NetBIOS on the DHCP server, follow these steps:
>
> - Click Start, point to Programs, point to Administrative Tools, and then click DHCP.
> - In the navigation pane, expand the `server_name`, expand Scope, right-click Scope Options, and then click Configure Options.
>
>   Note In this step, the `server_name` placeholder specifies the name of the DHCP server.
> - Click the Advanced tab, and then click Microsoft Windows 2000 Options in the Vendor class list.
> - Make sure that Default User Class is selected in the User class list.
> - Click to select the **001 Microsoft Disable Netbios Option** check box, under
>     the Available Options column.
> - In the Data entry area, type `0x2` in the Long box, and then click OK.

Comment: hm. yes. You are right. But how can this help me?
On another computer, where this forwarding is working, it gives be back: netstat -o -b|find ":445"
  TCP    10.255.255.1:445       192.168.177.27:51011     Connected 3364
  TCP    192.168.177.27:445     192.168.177.25:61561     Connected 4

Where 3364 is tasklist | find "3364"
svchost.exe                   3364 Services                   0        13.280 K, which is the lanmanserver described in https://www.nikhef.nl/~janjust/CifsOverSSH/Win8Loopback.html

Comment: It is a remote management service @GerdGruber You can disable the service. Check MS help articles on the same: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-manager/configure-remote-management-in-server-manager#BKMK_remote

Comment: The only difference between the old computer and the new compute is, that the old one was update from windows 7, and the new one has a full new windows 10 installation

Comment: `Port 445 is used by Windows http.sys` - I don't understand that. Port 445 is SMB-Direct (SMB over TCP). What does it have to do with http.sys?

Comment: I have no windows server nowhere.

Comment: `I have no windows server nowhere` - What do you mean by that? Port 445 is used in all versions and editions of Windows, not just Windows servers.

Comment: @joeqwerty Fixed the http.sys That was copying over error. I had the [su] article (linked in post above) fresh in mind.

Comment: it was a reply to the link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-manager/configure-remote-management-in-server-manager#BKMK_remote of hjpotter92 and it hint "It is a remote management servic". WinRM is disabled on my machine.

Comment: @GerdGruber I have updated the answer above.

Comment: @hjpotter92: OK. Understood. Thanks for the updated answer.

Answer (score -2):

the problem is the function NETBIOS over TCP/IP. Please disable it
(networkconfig, TCP/IP v4/advanced/WINS/NetBIOS over TCP/IP disable)

now it fully functionaly.

Kurt

Comment: The Original Upvoted answer, has a reference to [Configure the DHCP client to enable the DHCP server to determine NetBIOS behavior](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/disable-netbios-tcp-ip-using-dhcp) so this answer is a duplicate of the original one.